# Show/Hide div based on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my code :

**HTML** :

```
<Select id="colorselector">
   <option value="red-1">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow-2">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue-2">Blue</option>
   <option value="black-1">Black</option>
</Select>
<div id="-1" class="colors" style="display:none"> Div1... </div>
<div id="-2" class="colors" style="display:none"> Div2.. </div>
```

**JS** :

```
$(function() {
    $('#colorselector').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

What I want : when I select an option that contains `"-1"` the first div will appears, and the second div will disappear. And If I select an option that contains `"-2"` the firs div will disappear, and the second one will appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** to get the number

```js
$(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function() {
    $('.colors').hide();
    $('#-' + $(this).val().split('-')[1]).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector">
  <option value="red-1">Red</option>
  <option value="yellow-2">Yellow</option>
  <option value="blue-2">Blue</option>
  <option value="black-1">Black</option>
</Select>
<div id="-1" class="colors" style="display:none">Div1...</div>
<div id="-2" class="colors" style="display:none">Div2..</div>
```

Comment: Nice `$('#-' + $(this))` concatenates the parent ID with current option. `.val().split([separator][, limit])` specifies the character(s) to use for separating the string and sets limit on the number of splits to be found.

Comment: `'#-' + $(this).val().split('-')[1]` this code is to get the id that we need to show

Comment: Then I didn't get it, I'll do more research. Can you give a little more explanation? Haven't seen much of this before.

Comment: @Tim `$(this).val()` is for getting the value , `split('-')` for splitting the return value using `-` seperator, `[1]` is for getting the nuber from the returned array

Comment: Thanks I get it now, so split() returns substrings in an array. I haven't seen much of those `$('#-", + $(this)` contextual selectors before either. Great learnings!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**JS:**

```
$("#colorselector").change(function(){
    if((this.options[this.selectedIndex].value).indexOf("-1") > -1) {
        $("#-2").hide();
        $("#-1").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#-1").hide();
        $("#-2").show();
    }
});
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/r61pf8ra/)

Comment: I think the idea is for it to be expanded on. I.E. If the OP wanted to add a 3rd `.colors` `<div>`, the code would still work.

Comment: If that's the case then I would definetly prefer @Pranav's answer.